# Draw a matrix of numbers as an image with C++

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, graphic

I have a quite specific question: I want to draw a matrix of numbers in a greyscale image. The higher the number the brighter the output. Is there a way to do that in a C++ programme without having dependencies to a graphic library like Qt?

I looked through some examples of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/draw/), but I'm not sure how to implement its functions in C++.

**Answer**
In case someone stumbles upon this question:
a modified code of the example shown [here](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/start-linux.php) was a handy and easy solution

Comment: Of course there should be a way but this question is too broad.  If you have a question about a specific programming problem then ask that.

Comment: If it is so broad, why can't I find a solution? Any code example or helpful link would be great

Comment: The fundamental issues is that C++ has no facilities for images.  Images vary in their data structures (according to format), so a library is needed.  You can always check your OS to see if it has an API for drawing images.  This way you won't need Qt or ImageMagik.

Comment: I would say the easiest thing is to write a very simple `PGM` file and convert it to JPEG/PNG using ImageMagick later if necessary... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard without a library. [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.3/graphics-text.php) seems easy to use.

**EDIT**

Also you have 3 other questions hidden in your question:

1- To save an image you can use [sf::image::saveToFile](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php#aec0ed16b67df7b512aaa5c53388ba14e)

2- To get brighter number for higher number: You need to normalize your numbers to [MinColorYouWant MaxColorYouWant] (for example: [128,255]). Thus the normalization value corresponding to each number will become the color of the number.

3- [SFML uses RGBA](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Image.php#a1c2b960ea12bdbb29e80934ce5268ebf) images by default. Just set the RGB channels equal to make it look greyscale.

**EDIT 2** : I've fixed the example normalization from [128,256] to [128,255].

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped me.